# Postgres Database Exception

Tags: postgresql

Exception (Database Exception) 'yii\db\Exception' with message

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7
ERROR: a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
```

Comment: Please add your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a function that is defined as `RETURNS [SETOF] record`, you have to specify a column list when you call it. This is because the return type has to be known at query parse time.

An example:

```
SELECT * FROM myfun() AS myfun(a integer, b text);
```